# UInt32x32To64 identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com

I am coding in C++ and i am importing a C# class library using

```
#import "C:\abc\abc.tlb" 
using namespace XYZ;
```

When i do this i get an error in the file comutil.h
the error is
UInt32x32To64 identifier not found.I don't know i get this when i try to import a tlb file.
Can anyone help me in this matter?
This is where the portion of comutil.h

```
static HRESULT UIntMult(UINT uMultiplicand, UINT uMultiplier, UINT *puResult)
{
    ULONGLONG ull64Result = UInt32x32To64(uMultiplicand, uMultiplier);
    if(ull64Result <= INTSAFE_UINT_MAX)
    {
        *puResult = (UINT)ull64Result;
        return S_OK;
    }
    return INTSAFE_E_ARITHMETIC_OVERFLOW;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[`UInt32x32To64()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383741%28VS.85%29.aspx) is a macro defined in the Windows header files. You need to `#include <Windows.h>` to gain access to it.

---

Hans's comment is spot on. If you have `HRESULT` and `UINT` then presumably you have `Windows.h`. In which case the lack of the macro is presumably because the architecture conditional has not been defined.